# Oracle - Select Sum from other record in one table

Tags: oracle

I have problem with SQL Query like this:

MyTab1:

> Kode ----   Perkiraan --- Lvl --- GD --- DK --- REFF ---- N1 ------ N2 -----N3 ----- N4
>
> ```
> 10.000 Group I     1    G   D              0      0     0     0
> 10.100 test 1      2    G   D    10.000    0      0     0     0
> 10.101 test 1AA    3    D   D    10.100   10     20    15    15
> 10.102 test 1BB    3    D   D    10.100   15      5     0    20
> 10.200 test 2      2    G   D    10.100    0      0     0     0
> 10.201 test 2AA    2    D   D    10.200   30      0    10    20
> 10.202 test 2BB    2    D   D    10.200    0     50     3    50
> 20.000 Group II    1    G   K              0      0     0     0
> 20.100 test XY     1    G   K    20.000    0      0     0     0
> 20.101 test XY1    2    D   K    20.100   20     10    50    60
> 20.102 test XY2    2    D   K    20.100   10     10    50    50
> 20.200 test II     2    D   K    20.000    5      2     0     3
> ```

column N4 is from condition :

> if DK = D, N1 + N2 - N3
> if DK = K, N1 + N3 - N2

in my case, i want to make query with the result like this:

> Kode ----   Perkiraan --- Lvl --- GD --- DK --- REFF ---- N1 ------ N2 -----N3 ----- N4
>
> ```
> 10.000    Group I     1   G   D           55    50     0     0
> 10.100    test 1      2   G   D   10.000  25    25    15    25
> 10.101    test 1AA    3   D   D   10.100  10    20    15    15
> 10.102    test 1BB    3   D   D   10.100  15     5     0    20
> 10.200    test 2      2   G   D   10.100  30    50    13    67
> 10.201    test 2AA    2   D   D   10.200  30     0    10    20
> 10.202    test 2BB    2   D   D   10.200   0    50     3    47
> 20.000    Group II    1   G   K           35    22   200   223
> 20.100    test XY     1   G   K   20.000  30    20   100   110
> 20.101    test XY1    2   D   K   20.100  20    10    50    60
> 20.102    test XY2    2   D   K   20.100  10    10    50    50
> 20.200    test II     2   D   K   20.000   5    2      0     3
> ```

1. Criteria 1: lvl = 2, sum value from level 3 or appropriate with the value in REFF column.
2. Criteria 2: lvl = 1, sum value from level 2 or appropriate with the value in REFF column.
3. Criteria 3: lvl = 3, column N2 and N3 is a record value or it is likely from query join or sum from other table.

someone can help me please.....

Answer (score 0):

i don't fully understand your question but i'd look into

```
sum (y) over (partition by xx order by z)
```

etc

Comment: Halo Mr.. Thanks for answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr...

In my case, we can see at MyTab1:
we can see at fields KODE, the value from 10.000 to 10.102
10.000 is the top level (lvl), 10.100 is the 2nd level and 10.101 is the 3 level. level 3 is the Detail Data where in my case, level 3 is the transaction data.

default value in row level 1 and 2 is 0 ( I call 'G' = General, see field GD. 'G' General and 'D' is Detail ).

I want to make a query with result like a sample at the top. where the condition formula at level (lvl) 2 is formula **sum from all Level 3 and REFF = 10.100** and level 1 ( sum from level 2 ).

Example:

> ```
> Kode   Perkiraan  Lvl  GD   DK REFF     N1     N2    N3    N4    
> 10.000 Group I     1    G                0      0     0     0
> 10.100 test 1      2    G   D  10.000    0      0     0     0     
> 10.101 test 1AA    3    D   D  10.100   10     20    15    15    
> 10.102 test 1BB    3    D   D  10.100   15      5     0    20
> ```
>
> I want make result like this:
>
> ```
> 10.100 test 1      2    G   D  10.000   25     25    15    35
>
> N1 = 25 is from 10+15     
> N2 = 25 is from 20+5     
> N3 = 15 is from 15+0     and      
> N4 = 35 is from ( if Field DK = D, N1 + N2 - N3 and if DK = K then N1 + N3 - N2 ).
> ```

such was the case for level 1.

I difficulty to make the query..

Thanks for Your Interest and Best Regards..

Mulyadi.
Indonesia.